# printf problems, maybe just my code?

Tags: java

first time poster. I have created a dice simulation, in which it throws 2 dice, adds them together, counts the results and prints it. However, i can not get it to print it it the way i wish. This i show i am trying to make it looks like:

Sum       2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12

Antall    12 43 53 12 54 12 53 34 12 54 98

now it's vertical instead of horizontal.

this is my current code:

```
public static void skrivStatistikk() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int[] antall = new int[13]; {
    for (int kast = 1; kast <= 1000; kast++) {
        ++antall[1 + (rand.nextInt(6)) + (1 + rand.nextInt(6))];
    }
    System.out.printf("%s%10s\n", "Sum", "Antall");
    for (int side = 2; side < antall.length; side++) {
        System.out.printf("%4d%10d\n", side, antall[side]);
    }
}
```

EDIT: SOLVED
Pseudocode used is

1. print "Sum:"
2. for each s in sum:
3. print s
4. print a newline
5. print "Antall"
6. for each a in antall:
7. print a

Comment: Your printf's contain `\n`, which is a newline. So, of course you're going to get a newline. (As a general note, if you're wondering whether a method as old and universal as `printf` is broken, the answer is "no" 99.999% of the time.)

Comment: I am trying to make it 2 lines with Sum 2 3 4 5 6 7 etc. on one line, and then change the line before adding the second part. if i remove the \n's I only get a single line with the numbers scrambled. Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: You need to loop twice when printing -- once for "Sum" and once for "Antall."

Answer (score 0):

Remove the '\n' to not produce a new line when printing out lines.

Comment: This creates
Sum Antall 2  34 3 etc.
When i am looking for 
Sum 2 3 5 6 7 etc. |then a new line|
Antall 34 53 75 etc.

Comment: Have you tried combining your printfs as the problem is you try to write sum and antall in front of two different lines...

Comment: i just get SumSumSumsumSum over and over.I have no idea why it keeps repeating. Also how will i separate the two lines in one print?, by a "\n"?

Comment: I'm on my mobile so i can't give you a sample code. Try printing with two for and save side in an array too

Comment: Worked like a charm. I didn't save side in an array however.     print "Sum:"
 for each s in sum:
 print s
 print a newline
 print "Antall"
 for each a in antall:
 print a is the pseudocode i used.

Comment: I'm glad i could help. However I'm not posting code as I think that finding an answer by itself helps more. I would appreciate if you accept my answer